# 文字列（数字文字の出現回数）

Tags: c

ナル文字を使って、数字文字の出現回数を出力するプログラムを書きたいのですがうまくいきません。自分の見解では、間違っているところが見つけられないのですが、どこが間違っているのでしょうか。

ちなみに、自分は以下のようにプログラムしました。

```
void str_dcount(const char s[],int cnt[])
{
    int i;
    i=0;
    while(s[i]!='\0'){
        if('0'<=s[i] && s[i]<='9'){
            cnt[s[i]-'0']++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char str[128];
    int dcnt[10]={0};
    int i;
    printf("文字列? ");
    scanf("%s",str);
    str_dcount(str,dcnt);
    puts("数字文字の出現回数");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        putchar('\'');
        putchar('0'+i);
        putchar('\'');
        putchar(":%d\n",dcnt[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `putchar(":%d\n", dcnt[i]);` は `printf(":%d\n", dcnt[i]);` ではないでしょうか…………

Comment: 最後の`putchar`は`printf`の間違いですよね? 思い込みがあると、ちょっとした誤りも見つけにくくなるものです。「自分の見解では、間違っているところが見つけられない」(のに期待通りに動かない)と言う時ほど、丁寧に1行ずつ調べてみてください。

Comment: 単に「うまくいかない」ではなく、期待だとどう動いてほしくて、現状ではどんな問題があるのかをもう少し具体的に説明してみましょう。[ヘルプも参考に](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)。 / できればタイトルも、対面した相手に話しかけるつもりになって整理してみましょう。

Comment: metropolisさん、OOPerさんコメントの対処を行えば、入力桁数が少ないなら問題なく動作するでしょう。桁数が128以上になると、問題が起こる可能性があります(必ず起こるとは限りません)。こちらの記事を参考に考えてみてください。[標準入力から安全に文字列を受け取る方法いろいろ](https://qiita.com/mpyw/items/aff12a6ff2c7726ed1d8)

Comment: お返事ありがとうございます。確かにprintfであるべき場所がputcharになっていました。自分でもわかっていたことなので、これからは慎重かつ丁寧にプログラムしていこうと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[３つの文字列を連結するプログラムの書き方。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/61651/26370) の方で使い方に理解が不足しているように見えたので、こちらの対処方法も回答しておきます。

元の`scanf`でも良いのですが、新しいコンパイラでエラー、警告の出ないこちら [scanf_s、_scanf_s_l、wscanf_s、_wscanf_s_l](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=vs-2019) を使います。修正は`main`関数だけで、修正箇所にコメントを入れています。

```
int main(void)
{
    char str[128] = { 0 };/* 初期化しておく */
    int dcnt[10] = { 0 };
    int i;
    printf("文字列? ");
    scanf_s("%127s", str, 128); /* scanf_sに変更し、最大長を指定 */
    str_dcount(str, dcnt);
    puts("数字文字の出現回数");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        putchar('\'');
        putchar('0' + i);
        putchar('\'');
        printf(":%d\n", dcnt[i]); /* @metropolisさん、@OOPerさん指摘 */
    }
    return 0;
}
```